# Variable value in visual format langurage

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want to use variable value in visual format language.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary    = @{@"tblBuddyMessageList":tblBuddyMessageList,};
NSDictionary *matrixDictionary   = @{@"keyBoardHeight":};
arrCTtblBuddyMessageTopAndHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[tblBuddyMessageList]-260-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:arrCTtblBuddyMessageTopAndHeight];`
```

I want to use a variable instead of 260. How to do that ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:

Comment: `stringWithFormat:`?